# How to make viewWillAppear to be called when we use a subclass of UITableViewController to handle table delegate?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

I want to make my code more modular and flexible.

So rather than setting a the tableViewDelegate as the UIViewController, I have a subclass of UITableViewController as the tableView data source and delegate.

Basically, the original UIViewController provides the view for the subclass of UITableViewController.

That way similar tables can be used by several UIViewController's subclasses.

In some cases, UIViewController's provide the tableView and I just switch the tableView delegate at run time.

Works well.

Here is the code for BGTableViewDelegateMother that inherits from UITableViewController (that inherits from UIViewController.

```
@implementation BGTableViewDelegateMother

-(void) setDelegate:(id<BGTableViewDelegateMother>)delegate

{
    _delegate=delegate;

    self.view = self.delegate.tvDelegated; //So that viewWillAppear would work fine
    [self view]; //load the view view didload is not called either
    self.delegate.tvDelegated.delegate =self;
    self.delegate.tvDelegated.dataSource=self;
}
```

Okay. The UITableViewController.view is used for one thing. Now that it points to the correct tableView, I expect viewWillAppear to be called. It's not

I think everytime the tableView will be shown, I should at least reloadData

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];//never called
    [self.delegate.tvDelegated reloadData];
}
```

This code never called. Even though the view will indeed appear. Why?

viewDidLoad is also never called.

Answer (score 0):

Make the table view controller a child view controller of your view controller while its view is linked (and it is the data source) and could be on screen. This tells the view controller hierarchy that the table view needs to know about the appearance callbacks.